Flutter Bloc not updating state correctly when adding items to Hive Box
I'm working on a Flutter application where I'm using Bloc for state management and Hive for local storage. I'm facing an issue where the state is not updating correctly when I add an item to the cart. Specifically, when I add an item to the Hive Box, the Bloc does not seem to recognize the state change immediately.
It does recognize the change when I change page or hot-restart the app.
I did add List.from to try and create a new list to force a state change, since the way I understand is that Bloc won't emit a new state if it's identical to the last one.
If it helps, it doesn't seem to be emitting the CartLoadingState event as well.
Here is the code for my CartBloc:
class CartBloc extends Bloc<CartEvent, CartState> {
  final Box cartBox;

  CartBloc(this.cartBox) : super(CartInitialState()) {
    on<AddItemEvent>((event, emit) async {
      emit(CartLoadingState());
      print('AddItemEvent started');

      final existingItem = cartBox.values.firstWhere(
        (item) => (item as Map)['id_curso'] == event.courseItem.id,
        orElse: () => null,
      );

      if (existingItem == null) {
        final itemToAdd = event.courseItem.toMap()
          ..['tipo_certificado'] = event.certificateType == 'digital' ? '65' : '64';
        await cartBox.add(itemToAdd);
        print('Item added to cartBox');
      } else {
        print('Item already exists in cartBox');
      }

      final updatedCartItems = _getCartItems();
      emit(CartSuccessState(List.from(updatedCartItems), _calculateTotalPrice(updatedCartItems)));
      print('CartSuccessState emitted');
    });

    on<RemoveItemEvent>((event, emit) async {
      emit(CartLoadingState());
      print('RemoveItemEvent started');

      final key = cartBox.keys.firstWhere(
        (k) => (cartBox.get(k) as Map)['id_curso'] == event.id,
        orElse: () => null,
      );
      if (key != null) {
        await cartBox.delete(key);
        print('Item removed from cartBox');
      } else {
        print('Item not found in cartBox');
      }

      final updatedCartItems = _getCartItems();
      emit(CartSuccessState(List.from(updatedCartItems), _calculateTotalPrice(updatedCartItems)));
      print('CartSuccessState emitted');
    });

    on<ClearCartEvent>((event, emit) async {
      emit(CartLoadingState());
      print('ClearCartEvent started');

      await cartBox.clear();
      print('All items removed from cartBox');

      final updatedCartItems = _getCartItems();
      emit(CartSuccessState(List.from(updatedCartItems), _calculateTotalPrice(updatedCartItems)));
      print('CartSuccessState emitted');
    });

    on<GetCartItemsEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(CartLoadingState());
      print('GetCartItemsEvent started');

      final updatedCartItems = _getCartItems();
      emit(CartSuccessState(List.from(updatedCartItems), _calculateTotalPrice(updatedCartItems)));
      print('CartSuccessState emitted');
    });
  }

  List<UserCourseModel> _getCartItems() {
    return cartBox.values.map((item) {
      final map = Map<String, dynamic>.from(item as Map);
      return UserCourseModel.fromMap(map);
    }).toList();
  }

  double _calculateTotalPrice(List<UserCourseModel> cartItems) {
    return cartItems.fold(0.0, (sum, item) => sum + double.parse(item.certificatePrice.replaceAll(',', '.')));
  }
}

And here is a snippet of the UI code that triggers the AddItemEvent:
onTap: () {
       cartBloc.add(AddItemEvent(course, 'printed'));
       Navigator.of(context).pop();
 },

Code for CartState:
abstract class CartState extends Equatable {}

class CartInitialState implements CartState {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];

  @override
  bool get stringify => false;
}

class CartLoadingState implements CartState {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];

  @override
  bool get stringify => false;
}

class CartSuccessState implements CartState {
  final List<UserCourseModel> cartItems;
  final double totalPrice;

  CartSuccessState(this.cartItems, this.totalPrice);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [cartItems, totalPrice];

  @override
  bool get stringify => false;
}

class CartErrorState implements CartState {
  final String message;

  const CartErrorState(this.message);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [message];

  @override
  bool get stringify => false;
}

And CartEvent:
abstract class CartEvent {}

class AddItemEvent extends CartEvent {
  final UserCourseModel courseItem;
  final String certificateType;

  AddItemEvent(this.courseItem, this.certificateType);
}

class RemoveItemEvent extends CartEvent {
  final String id;

  RemoveItemEvent(this.id);
}

class ClearCartEvent extends CartEvent {}

class GetCartItemsEvent extends CartEvent {}

What might be causing the state not to update immediately in the UI?
UserCourseModel class:
class UserCourseModel {
  final String toId;
  final String id;
  final String userId;
  final String status;
  final String name;
  final String imgUrl;
  final String certificatePrice;
  final String digitalCertificatePrice;
  final String initDate;
  final String? conclusionDate;
  final String? certificateType;
  final List<ModuleModel> modules;

  UserCourseModel({
    required this.toId,
    required this.id,
    required this.userId,
    required this.status,
    required this.name,
    required this.imgUrl,
    required this.certificatePrice,
    required this.digitalCertificatePrice,
    required this.initDate,
    this.conclusionDate,
    this.certificateType,
    required this.modules,
  });

  factory UserCourseModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return UserCourseModel(
      toId: map['id_to'] as String,
      id: map['id_curso'] as String,
      userId: map['id_usuario'] as String,
      status: map['status_curso'] as String,
      name: map['nome_curso'] as String,
      imgUrl: map['img_url'] as String,
      certificatePrice: map['preco_certificado'] as String,
      digitalCertificatePrice: map['preco_certificado_digital'] as String,
      initDate: map['data_inicio_curso'] as String,
      conclusionDate: map['data_conclusao_curso'] as String? ?? '',
      certificateType: map['tipo_certificado'] as String? ?? '',
      modules: (map['curso']['lista_modulos'] as List)
          .map((item) => ModuleModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>.from(item)))
          .toList(),

    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id_to': toId,
      'id_curso': id,
      'id_usuario': userId,
      'status_curso': status,
      'nome_curso': name,
      'img_url': imgUrl,
      'preco_certificado': certificatePrice,
      'preco_certificado_digital': digitalCertificatePrice,
      'data_inicio_curso': initDate,
      'data_conclusao_curso': conclusionDate ?? '',
      'tipo_certificado': certificateType ?? '',
      'curso': {
        'lista_modulos': modules.map((module) => module.toMap()).toList(),
      },
    };
  }
}

class ModuleModel {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String totalTopics;
  final List<TopicModel> topics;

  ModuleModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.totalTopics,
    required this.topics,
  });

  factory ModuleModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ModuleModel(
      id: map['id_modulo'] as String,
      name: map['nome_modulo'] as String,
      totalTopics: map['total_topicos'] as String,
      topics: (map['lista_topicos'] as List)
          .map((item) => TopicModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>.from(item)))
          .toList(),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id_modulo': id,
      'nome_modulo': name,
      'total_topicos': totalTopics,
      'lista_topicos': topics.map((topic) => topic.toMap()).toList(),
    };
  }
}

class TopicModel {
  final String orderPosition;
  final String id;
  final String moduleId;
  final String title;

  TopicModel({
    required this.orderPosition,
    required this.id,
    required this.moduleId,
    required this.title,
  });

  factory TopicModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return TopicModel(
      orderPosition: map['ordem_posicao'] as String,
      id: map['id_topico'] as String,
      moduleId: map['id_modulo'] as String,
      title: map['titulo_topico'] as String,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'ordem_posicao': orderPosition,
      'id_topico': id,
      'id_modulo': moduleId,
      'titulo_topico': title,
    };
  }
}



show UserCourseModel

Added as requested.

As you said:
'Bloc won't emit a new state if it's identical to the last one.'
And it is a big probability that this is the reason. Your models UserCourseModel, TopicModel, ModuleModel are identical in emitted states.To avoid this you should override equals and hashcode for each of them. A common practice to avoid doing this manually for each model is to use packages like equatable, freezed etc

Following your advice and also changing my CartBloc from Factory to Singleton in my GetIt dependencies has resolved the issue for not updating the Cart in real time. Thank you.

yes, I definitely missed the block creation point

Not your fault, I didn't post it assuming that it was correct. My bad.
